# Mysql running total from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to execute subquery running total or cumulative sum from 2 tables? The results will be saved as 'New Value'.

First table :

```
CREATE TABLE data2 ( date1 DATE,mt int);

INSERT INTO data2 VALUES ('2018-01-01',76564);
INSERT INTO data2 VALUES ('2018-02-01',140005);
INSERT INTO data2 VALUES ('2018-03-01',231973);
INSERT INTO data2 VALUES ('2018-04-01',340085);
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE bajet ( date1 DATE,mt int);

INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-05-01',108344);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-06-01',108349);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-07-01',108338);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-08-01',108329);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-09-01',108311);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-10-01',108325);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-11-01',108330);
INSERT INTO bajet VALUES ('2018-12-01',108331);
```

Expected Result :

[image]

Comment: What is the `new value` calculated? How do you calculate it?

Comment: Shouldn't the second row in 'new value' have (76567 + 1400006) rather than 140008?

Comment: @Amirul Fahmi: Your question appears unclear, details are missing, please update your question with proper details.

Comment: Dont mind the 'new value' values. The idea is to calculate cumulative sum from these 2 tables.

Comment: How does 76564 turn into 76567 in the first row?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `new value` field is running total across the two tables based on date, the below query should work for you.

```
SELECT t.date, t.mt, 
         (@running_total := @running_total + t.mt) AS new_value
FROM (
  SELECT date1 date, mt from data2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date1 date, mt from bajet
) AS t
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
ORDER BY t.date;
```